# In the official document of CnosDB,What do "must_change_password" and "rsa_public_key" mean and how should they be used

Tags: cnosdb

In the section, it only describes how to create users, but there is no description and usage of "must_change_password" and "rsa_public_key" fields. I want to know how to use it
[image: Missing these two keywords]

The "must_change_password" field can be set when creating a user

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS tester WITH PASSWORD='xxx',MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD=true,COMMENT = 'test';
```

When the user table is queried, you can see the "must_change_password" and "rsa_public_key" field

```
SELECT * FROM cluster_schema.users;
user_name | is_admin | user_options
root      | true     | {"password":"*****","must_change_password":true,"rsa_public_key":null,"comment":"system admin"}
```

Comment: This is not an issue tracker for third-party project. This is a Question & Answer site. If you want to report improvements to a project, you should report them to that project itself. A good starting point would probably be https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb